# PHP preg_replace odd characters not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following code, but for some reason, the characters are not replaced....

test.php

```
<?php
$s = 'AABBCC����ˮ��������Ƽ���� �˾XXYYZZ';
$softwareVersion = preg_replace('[^a-zA-Z\d\s\.]', '', $s);
echo $softwareVersion . "\n";
```

what I am getting

```
jeffreylroberts:~$ php test.php
AABBCC����ˮ��������Ƽ���� �˾XXYYZZ
jeffreylroberts:~$
```

what I am expecting

```
jeffreylroberts:~$ php test.php
AABBCC XXYYZZ
jeffreylroberts:~$
```

Any ideas on how to preg_replace those characters?

Comment: Which characters *are* you trying to replace?

Comment: non-alphanumeric with the exception of spaces and periods

Comment: First of, you're missing the regex delimiters.

Comment: please provide a code snippet of the correct way

Comment: @JeffreyL.Roberts Eduardo's right: [see here](https://3v4l.org/mF9If).

Comment: https://3v4l.org/mmHIq

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230676/hey-you-yeah-you-post-your-answers-as-answers-not-comments/296481#296481

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a leading an trailing forward slash in the regex, This will give you the output you need:

```
$softwareVersion = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\d\s\.]/', '', $s);
```

Also you can do it this way, which will remove all characters except alphanumeric and underscore:

```
$softwareVersion = preg_replace('/\W/', '', $s);
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to tweak:

- Use a pattern delimiter.  `/` is the most common one.
- Reduce your pattern length by only writing `a-z` in the character class and use the `i` modifier/flag at the end of your pattern.
- Escaping the dot is not necessary in the character class.
- Use the `+` "one or more" quantifier to improve efficiency.  It will match consecutive occurrences of character and replace the multi-character substring in one shot.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/009bcb3a12957d574191982e7d1349a6f7b54b49))

```
$s='AABBCC����ˮ��������Ƽ���� �˾XXYYZZ';
$softwareVersion = preg_replace('/[^a-z\d\s.]+/i','',$s);
echo $softwareVersion . "\n";
```

Output:

```
AABBCC XXYYZZ
```